# add functions to raphael js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to add a function to raphael that draws a calender with no success.

Here is my code:

```
Raphael.fn.calenderView = function () {

};

$(function () {
    var paper = Raphael('body');
    paper.calenderView();
});
```

The error that I am getting is that paper has no method calenderView. There is probably something blatantly wrong and maybe I'm just to tired to see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$(function () {
    Raphael.fn.calenderView = function () {alert("calendar");};
    var paper = new Raphael(0,0,200,200);
    paper.calenderView();
});​
```

See example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/58yqW/

Comment: this does work, but could someone explain to my why the function has to be made inside the document ready function

Comment: The function just has to be assigned AFTER Raphael is loaded.  It shouldn't have to wait until DOM ready.

Comment: @jfriend00 is correct, my example uses dom ready to keep with your example code, its your choice how you implement it, I've merely shown you one way that DOES WORK!